# Django I Can't add a fields to my model form?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to add a fields to my model but it not working.
the field that I want to add it `content_list = models.TextField(null=True)`

models.py

```
class number(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    num = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    content_list = models.TextField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item
```

When I run the `manage.py makemigrations` is working, so after that I run the `manage.py migrate` and it give me this error

`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: new__promo_number.content`
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete all old migrations files in migrations Directory and try again!